# Finding multiple lines with a regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to complete a "Regex search" project from the book [Automate boring stuff with python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/). I tried searching for answer, but I failed to find related thread in python.

The task is: "Write a program that opens all .txt files in a folder and searches for any line that matches a user-supplied regular expression. The results should be printed to the screen."

With the below compile I manage to find the first match

```
regex = re.compile(r".*(%s).*" % search_str)
```

And I can print it out with

```
print(regex.search(content).group())
```

But if I try to use

```
print(regex.findall(content))
```

The output is only the inputted word/words, not the whole line they are on. Why won't `findall` match the whole line, even though that is how I compiled the regex?

My code is as follows.

```
# Regex search - Find user given text from a .txt file
# and prints the line it is on

import re

# user input
print("\nThis program searches for lines with your string in them\n")
search_str = input("Please write the string you are searching for: \n")
print("")
# file input
file = open("/users/viliheikkila/documents/kooditreeni/input_file.txt")
content = file.read()
file.close()

# create regex
regex = re.compile(r".*(%s).*" % search_str)

# print out the lines with match
if regex.search(content) is None:
    print("No matches was found.")
else:
    print(regex.findall(content))
```

Comment: P.S. I am new to programming and to stackoverflow, so all the help is appreciated. Also if I broke any rules of conduct, please let me know, so I will know better next time. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community. You don't need grouping at all `.*%s.*`

Comment: Thanks mate! This was not the first time that unnecessary brackets ruin my code.

Answer (score 0):

In python regex, parentheses define a *capturing group*. (See [here](https://regex101.com/r/iV8nS1/1) for breakdown and explanation).

`findall` will only return the captured group. If you want the entire line, you will have to iterate over the result of `finditer`.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I got my code actually to run by removing the parentheses. And thanks for an excellent link.